# python unicode: what codec will preserve literal byte values?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I need to decode a byte string into unicode, and insert it into a unicode string (python 2.7).  When I later encode that unicode string back into bytes, the byte array must be equal to the original bytes.  My question is which encoding I should use to achieve this.

Example:

```
#every possible byte
byteString = b"".join([chr(ii) for ii in xrange(256)])
unicodeString = u"{0}".format(byteString.decode("ascii"))
backToBytes = unicodeString.encode("ascii")
assert byteString==backToBytes
```

This fails with the infamous:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 128: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**What encoding should I use here (instead of 'ascii') to preserve my byte values?**

I am using "ascii" in this (currently broken) example, because it is my default encoding:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
```

Answer (score 1):

**It turns out that the 'latin1' (aka 'iso-8859-1') encoding will preserve every byte literally.** [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925458/iso-8859-1-encoding-and-binary-data-preservation) mentions this fact, although [other sources](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html#8) led me to believe this was false.  I can confirm that running this code on python 2.7 works, demonstrating that 'iso-8859-1' does indeed preserve every possible byte:

```
#every possible byte
byteString = b"".join([chr(ii) for ii in xrange(256)])
unicodeString = u"{0}".format(byteString.decode("iso-8859-1"))
backToBytes = unicodeString.encode("iso-8859-1")
assert byteString==backToBytes
```

Comment: The gap you see in that “other source” are control characters: U+0080 to U+009C are control characters. The same goes for bytes 0 to 31, and byte 127.

Comment: Python 2/3 version: `all_bytes = bytearray(range(0x100));` `all_bytes.decode('latin1').encode('latin1') == all_bytes` (note: [this encoding may be interpreted differently in different contexts e.g., python executable and a web browser may use different definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19110555/4279). iso-8859-1 doesn't support all Unicode characters and therefore you can't use it to encode an arbitrary Unicode string e.g., `u"\N{SNOWMAN}".encode('latin1')` fails. To pass arbitrary bytes as Unicode, you could use something like `'surrogateescape'` handler from Python 3.