# Largest binary type size with PHP

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, bit, bitmask, operation

I am working on an algorithm and I need to do lots of `array_intersect` and it takes a long time. So today I came up to the idea of using bits and the operator `&` to intersect my "arrays".

Something like this:

```
$x1 = 0b1000100;
$x2 = 0b0100100;
$x3 = 0b0100101;

$intersected = $x1 & $x2 & $x3;
```

My problem: I need to use at least 30.000 bits per variable, something like `0b0100110101010101001.......0101010` (30k bits). I know there are limits on PHP to `int` and `float` which depends on the processor architecture (x86 or x64) but in my understanding there is no limit to strings size (of course RAM would be a limit). So if I cant use the binary type to save my 30k bits, can I save it in a string or something like that and still being able to do bit operations?

Comment: You need a "Bit Array" data structure, sometimes also called "Bit Vector". AFAIK - there's no built-in bit array in PHP. But there are free solutions out there on GitHub.

Comment: @AlexShesterov I found CPKS on GitHub and does what you said! But I think it's "too complicated" to do a simple thing. I am wondering: how does PHP store a string? Certainly, at the core, a long string is just bits, lots of bits. Cant I use strings to do what I need?

Comment: Well you could store it as a string and then split it into two parts of bits on the check.

Comment: Guys!!! I just discovered right now that if I do 'aaaabbbbbbaaaaa' & 'aaaabbabbbaaaaa' works perfectly! I have no idea the performance, I will test it now.

Comment: @ThomasJ.the overhead of doing that on a 30k bits, splitting in thousans of bytes, would not provide any benefit over array_intersect.

Comment: As long as you understand that you are working in ASCII when doing this, you should be fine, I guess. `('a' & 'b') === chr(96)`, since `a` is ASCII 97, `b` is ASCII 98. After 127, I'm not sure what characters to use and if they will be [consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19109899/231316), but you are probably safe as long as you stay on the same machine.

Comment: @ChrisHaas that's correct! Thank you so much!!! I am using 0 and 1 in the string (instead of `a` and `b` as I said earlier) and it works exactly as expected! Exactly like using `0b000` type.