# How to detect the right file encoding with python?

Tags: python, character-encoding

I try to read a csv (from https://openwrt.org/_media/toh_dump_tab_separated.zip) in python with pandas using pandas.read_csv().
The problem is the encoding of the file. It is not UTF-8, it is not Latin1. And I don't want to go manually through all the codecs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

The workaround is opening the file in Libre Office, replacing weird characters with '-', saving as Latin1 and opening in Python.

How do I do it in Python only?

The following code and error are my current status with UTF-8:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('../../Downloads/toh_dump_tab_separated/ToH_dump_tab_separated.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

(...)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 983: invalid start byte

and with Latin1:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('../../Downloads/toh_dump_tab_separated/ToH_dump_tab_separated.csv', encoding = 'Latin1')
```

(...)

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2

Comment: Encoding appears to be `cp1252`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sep` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('ToH_dump_tab_separated.csv', encoding = 'cp1252', sep='\t')
print(df)
```

> ```
>           pid  ...                                           comments
> 0       16132  ...                                                NaN
> 1       16133  ...                                                NaN
> 2       16134  ...                                                NaN
> 3       16135  ...                           Clone of Aztech HW550-3G
> 4       16137  ...  Image build disabled in master with commit d7d...
> ...       ...  ...                                                ...
> 1759  9726386  ...                                                NaN
> 1760  9878711  ...  Rough edges as of December 2020. Realtek targe...
> 1761  9912125  ...  Works with WL-WN575A3 image according OpenWrt ...
> 1762  9927580  ...                                                NaN
> 1763  9946488  ...                                                NaN
>
> [1764 rows x 67 columns]
> ```

FYI, the *weird* character `0xbf` is  `¿` *Inverted Question Mark* `U+00BF` (or `\u00BF`):

```
print( df.switch[:2]); print( df.fccid[-2:])
```

> ```
> 0    Infineon ADM6996I
> 1                    ¿
> Name: switch, dtype: object
> 1762                    http://¿
> 1763    https://fcc.io/Q87-03331
> Name: fccid, dtype: object
> ```

**Edit** (tnx **Mark Tolonen**). Encoding appears to be `cp1252`. There are smart quotes in some of the fields:

```
print( df.comments[254][288:])
```

> ```
> Ignore the “HW v” on the label - it may not say 2 for v2 hardware
> ```

Comment: Encoding appears to be `cp1252`.  There are smart quotes in some of the fields.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
But how do you know that it is cp1252, @MarkTolonen ? Just by rolling the magic codec dice, or looking sharp at the characters and have a good knowledge about codecs?

Comment: @Cyoux Option 2.I loaded the data and created a `set` of the content less the `set` of ASCII characters, and was left with a few French accents and smart quotes when opened as `cp1252`. `latin1` doesn’t support smart quotes. 1252 is a common codec for US and Western European Windows.

Comment: @Cyoux read this thread: [What is the exact difference between Windows-1252(1/3/4) and ISO-8859-1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19109899/3439404)